# How would you use killBackgroundProcesses in Android

Tags: android

Well, hello..
I have a question, how would you correctly use this
    "ActivityManager.killBackgroundProcesses(String packageName)"

I have tried to replace packagename with a package, for now let's call it com.example.package.
It doesn't seem to be compiling it as it pops up with errors (I am new to Android app developing)

Would appreciate any help! =)

Comment: Obviously, with instance of AcivityManager as it is not a static method... Please, learn some java's basics.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] demonstrating the code that you are trying that is not compiling, and indicate what compile errors you are getting.

Answer (score 0):

You must have a special permission to kill background processes from your application. Add the following permission in your manifest.

> "uses-permission android:name="android.permission.KILL_BACKGROUND_PROCESSES"

The above permission enables to kill any background process running for the package name provided in "ActivityManager.killBackgroundProcesses(String packageName)"